# How to loop tests in Selenium IDE?

Tags: testing, selenium-ide

I've been testing in Selenium IDE. It's pretty easy to use, and I have created some test cases with it. I've been searching Google, trying to find a way to repeat my tests automatically. I've seen a solution with gotolabel, while loops, etc. But I couldn't make any of them works. Can someone give me a tip on how to loop my test `n` times, or loop forever. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Do this:

1. Download this js file: https://github.com/darrenderidder/sideflow/blob/master/sideflow.js
2. Launch Selenium IDE from Firefox and open the options menu.
3. Upload the .js file to the "Selenium Core extensions (user-extensions.js)" field.

The js file provides goto, gotoIf and while loop functionality in Selenium IDE. The example below shows a simple loop:

```
<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>index = 0;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>while</td>
    <td>index &lt; 10;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>index</td>
    <td>value</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${value}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>index++;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>endWhile</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Selenium IDE says `[error] Unknown command: 'while'`.

Answer (score 55):

No need to install/download anything, the built-in [times](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/control-flow/#times-selenium-ide-docs-en-api-commands-times) command does this very easily:

1. Insert a new line at the beginning of your script, select `times` as its `Command` and `10` (for instance) as its `Target`.
2. Scroll down to the bottom of your script, and add a new line with `end` as its command
3. Press the "Run" button as usual.
4. Your commands are executed 10 times.

In this example I click on a button 2000 times:

[image]

To loop forever, just replace `10` with an extremely large number, that will take centuries to execute, which probably is as good as forever if you are running Selenium IDE.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 17):

as stated in the answer above, install the user extension, which will add loop functionality to Selenium IDE tests. The example below shows a simple loop:

```
<tr>
<td>getEval</td>
<td>index = 0;</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>while</td>
<td>index &lt; 10;</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td>index</td>
<td>value</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${value}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>getEval</td>
<td>index++;</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>endWhile</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm new to Selenium (just started using it a few minutes ago). After a quick Google search for "selenium loop" this stackoverflow.com question came up. I immediately jumped into the extension and started using loops. The accepted answer is very helpful. However, I wanted to point out something else for others that are new to selenium (and stumble on this page).

I created a simple test for a simple web page. I added a loop so that the test would run indefinitely (until I paused/stopped it). However, I noticed that by doing this, the Runs/Failures counters within the Selenium GUI do not increment with each loop (I am guessing because a single test case was never running to completion, it was just looping indefinitely). So I dug a bit further. My goal was to leave the same test running for a long time (a few hours, or possibly overnight) to see if there were any failures (I'm chasing an intermittent bug at the moment).

The simplest way (for me, after a few minutes of searching/experimenting) was to do the following (likely no plugins needed, although the attached plugin is definitely helpful if you want to run a few small loops within a test case):

- save the test case to a text file
- save the test suite to a text file
- open the test suite text file in a text editor
- copy and paste the test case multiple times within the test suite (for example, a thousand times)
- then open the test suite in Selenium, and run the test suite

Now I have the same simple test suite running many times, and the Runs/Failures counters are incrementing as expected (without the need for any loops).

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Flow Control plug-in for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flow-control/). After restarting Firefox, use the `label` command to mark a point in the script, and the `gotolabel` command to jump there.

For example:

[image]

Or if you'd rather see the source code, this is a label:

```
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>start</td>  
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

And this causes the execution point to jump back to the label:

```
<tr>
    <td>gotolabel</td>
    <td>start</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

There are other commands that you can see on the plug-in page, and documented in the
[Selenium IDE: Flow Control GitHub project](https://github.com/davehunt/selenium-ide-flowcontrol).

Comment: The Firefox extension you mentioned no longer available to download/install.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium IDE now has flow control. These Control Flow commands work by specifying opening and closing commands to denote a set (or block) of commands.

**Available Commands**

Here are each of the available control flow commands accompanied by their companion and/or closing commands.

if, else if, else, end
times, end
do, repeat if
while, end

You can read more about it here:

https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/control-flow/

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample for sampcop user in order to automate spam complaints using label and goto Label commands:

1st Login on spamcop.net

2nd use Report Spam option

3rd start this script

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://www.spamcop.net/sc" />
<title>testecase</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">testecase</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>

<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>target1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Report Now</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//input[@value='Send Spam Report(s) Now']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoLabel</td>
    <td>target1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my script depends on seleniun core extension by Prashant Vadher

Answer (score 1):

Your test suite file is just an HTML file, so just do the following:

```html
<tr><td><a href="testCase1.html">testCase1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="sameStep.html">sameStep</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="testCase2.html">testCase1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="sameStep.html">sameStep</a></td></tr>
```