# looping a selenium script until you find an element

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I am trying to create a Selenium IDE script that will hit a page until a specific element appears.

For example, I want to keep hitting search on the main ebay page until an ad that my company pays for comes up.  The ad has a distinct element ID so I am good there, but what I am having a hard time with is the looping.  Is it possible to add in an "If, then" statement into the script to make it restart if the element isn't found and then another to have the script stop once it hits the page where the element is found?  Or is there another suggestion that one of the great minds out there can help with?

Thank you!

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033321/how-to-loop-tests-in-selenium-ide) the answer you're looking for

Comment: @Alexander-Petrovich, thank you for the feedback.  That comment is actually what led me here to stackoverflow, but I see that as a loop with a purpose of running 10 times.  I need to loop UNTIL I hit the element I am looking for (in this case, an advertisement with a unique ID).