# Selenium IDE Loop Conditions

Tags: selenium, while-loop, automated-tests

I am first time using Selenium for automating some developer tests.

I have some intermediate steps, which needs to run based on certain condition like a `while` loop

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//a[contains(text(),'active listings')]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

//while(delist elementPresent) -----------------------------
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>name=delist</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=listing_check_all</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>name=delist</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>verifyElementPresent</td>    ------------repeated step
    <td>name=delist</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=listing_check_all</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>name=delist</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
//end while (i.e. delist element no longer present) ---------------
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>No active listings found</td>
</tr>
```

One more question, can I automate this process from command line?
I can write a script (.bat/.sh) to automate the test case run.

*Note: Please do understand that I am using selenium for the first time, just to automate few dev tests.*

Comment: Hi, maybe here you will find your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033321/how-to-loop-tests-in-selenium-ide

If you are good in programming try to write some selenium test for webdriver...

Comment: @AndrianDurlestean, can you write a sample how to do it for my case

Comment: I never tried to loop in Selenium IDE, you can try the link to solution I gave to you, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium IDE doesn't give looping functionality, you will need to install an add on like this: https://github.com/darrenderidder/sideflow

Comment: I am ready to install. Thing is, can you give me sample or how to write modify my test case as i explained in original post

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins you can add to Selenium IDE that will help you accomplish loops.  You can look at a list of plugins [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

I believe the plugin you're look to achieve the **while** loop with is called [SelBlocks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/).  I believe the Flow Control plugin does this as well.  I've used this in the past with great success.  A few things to note though:

(1) Don't expect documentation for these commands to show up in the Reference tab.  You'll have to read the Selblocks Reference page listed with the plugin for examples on how to implement its commands.

(2) If you intend to export your 'Selenese' code over to Java, C#, Python, or any other language, these commands won't export over.  You'll have to hard code anything you created that's directly associated with any plugin command('s) you used (i.e. while, for, if, etc...) in that programming language's native code.

Hope this helps someone out.